# Fix X11 forwarding on OSX

Tags: x11, osx, bacula

I am looking for a way to fix/debug a X11 forwarding session on OSX.
Here is my situation:

- From my mac I connect to a Ubuntu workstation with `ssh -X` (tried `ssh -Y` as well).
- X11 forwarding works perfectly with firefox for instance, X11/Quartz is started automatically on OSX and firefox is displayed.
- X11 forwarding does not work with bat (Bacula graphical console): X11 is started but no window is displayed. There are no errors (`/private/var/log/system.log`).

When I try doing the same from another Ubuntu workstation, it works perfectly for both firefox and bat.

I guess the problem is on OSX side then. I tried switching some options in X11 but nothing works. Would you have any idea on how to move forward?

Comment: It doesn't look like exactly the same problem, but maybe it's relevant: http://robert.penz.name/354/how-to-fix-the-font-for-virt-manager-via-x-forwarding/

Comment: Try googling _bacula xquartz_ for other issues

Comment: @Networker actually, no, Bacula Admin Too (`bat`) is part of the backup system.

Comment: @countermode `bat` is part of Bacula. Plop "Bacula bat" into Google and you'll get plenty of details, e.g., http://www.baculasystems.com/bat-the-bacula-administration-tool

Comment: BTW: I've edited the [tag:bacula] tag description to help avoid this in the future.

Comment: Ah. I see.  Btw., tag references are created `[tag:like_so]`.